# Use Timber/Twig to pull an image by image ID

Tags: php, templates, attachments, images

Is it possible to use Twig to pull an image by ID, or only to pull the `post.thumbnail`? The Twig docs don't seem to cover any other image need and I'd like to specify a backup image in case no `post.thumbnail` is found.

I think what I need is something like `wp_get_attachment_image_src(1234,'medium_16x9')` but in Twig's language.

```
    <a href="{{post.link}}">
        {% if post.thumbnail %}
        <img src="{{ post.thumbnail.src('medium_16x9') }}">
        {% else %}
        <img src="{{ wp_get_attachment_image_src(1234,'medium_16x9') }}">
        {% endif %}
    </a>
```

I suppose I could set this up in the PHP by adding the backup image URL to a variable, but this means I'd have to add that code to every PHP file that calls this twig. It's better to grab the image in the twig, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{{ post.thumbnail.ID }}` will get you the image ID, but to answer what you're after....

```
<img src="{{ post.thumbnail.src('medium_16x9') | default( Image(1234).src('medium_16x9') ) }}">
```

[Reference](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html)

Comment: That's brilliant. It would be useful if that were in the twig docs!

Comment: @Jared everyone uses your plugin and you're always answering questions on it, howcome you've got such a little rep in the WP StackExchange?

Comment: @pythonian29033 looks like I've answered too many Qs on StackOverflow where I'm at 743, and not enough on the WP StackExchange — is there a way to link those accounts?

Comment: @Jared naa, as far as I know they're already connected that's why you got 100 rep when you joined here (you should have), but the rep is decoupled and site specific